# How to check if a substring is in any of the entries in rows of an excel sheet?

Tags: excel, substring, vlookup

So I basically have a table with multiple columns.

[image]

So for each of the ids (1, 2, 3), I would like to check in which column there is sub-string of * (as you see sometimes it's in B and sometimes in C). Then I would like to extract the whole string that contains * and is associated with the given ID.

*Suppose that my actual table contains over 10 columns - but the idea remains the same.* 
In other words the entries that I am looking for that contain a specific substring are scatted all throughout the 10 different columns.

Comment: What if it is in both columns?

Comment: That's impossible in this case - assume that's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HLOOKUP

```
=HLOOKUP("*~**",B1:C1,1,FALSE)
```

Since the asterisk(*) is a wildcard we need to append it with the tilde(~) to tell Search to look for the actual character.

The outer `*` allow the HLOOKUP to look at part.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I have about 10 different columns for all of which I would have to write a nested IF. Is there a way to do this with HLookup? Thanks!

Comment: You should be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function FindTheStar(rng As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range, v As String
    FindTheStar = ""
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Text
        If InStr(v, "*") > 0 Then
            FindTheStar = v
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

It will find and return the first cell in any range that contains an asterisk.

[image]